# CSS link in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

my css in following folder :

**assets/css/theme.css**

I add it to :

**layout/admin_header.blade.html**

But it does not work . Looking forward for help .

Comment: show us some code on how you added it into your view. And for the blade, it must be .php, not .html

Comment: add it in public/css and then use <link  href="{{ asset('css/file.css') }}" ... in your default.blade.php

Comment: sorry it is my typing mistake it is  **layout/admin_header.blade.php**     and  I link css using    **<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css"/>**

Comment: it's working now?

Comment: ensure assets directory is inside laravel public directory

Comment: No. Now I add **<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/theme.css') }}" />** But still same problem.   <br>  file structure is **views/layouts/admin_header.blade.php**  <br>  and I add it to **views/dashboard.blade.php**

Comment: Simply ensure `assets/css/theme.css` is inside laravel public directory i.e `public/assets/css/theme.css`

Comment: Problem Solved . I kept CSS file in resource/assets . Now change file destination to public/assets. Now it works well . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`resource/assets` is for storing assets which you can use toolkit like gulpjs to compress, minify or move to pubic directory. `/resources/assets` is not accessible via URL.

Simply ensure assets/css/theme.css is inside laravel public directory i.e `public/assets/css/theme.css`